# Keras problem -----> ValueError: Unknown layer:name

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/TheophileBuy/LicensePlateRecognition) project. But when I try to run "finalPrototype.py" an error show up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finalPrototype.py", line 15, in <module>
    characterRecognition = tf.keras.models.load_model('character_recognition.h5')
  ....................................................................................
  File "C:\Users\sajal\anaconda3\envs\python-cvcourse\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 193, in deserialize_keras_object
    function_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer:name
```

I searched for it and found something in [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11617) but it didn't solve my issue. I had updated keras version but didn't help. It is an existing project and I belive there should be version issue among the packages. I am using anaconda distribution and all the package versions are below:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
asgiref==3.2.7
astor==0.8.0
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
autobahn==20.3.1
Automat==20.2.0
awscli==1.18.27
backcall==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
bleach==3.1.4
botocore==1.15.27
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
cmake==3.17.1
colorama==0.4.3
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.16
dateparser==0.7.4
DateTime==4.3
decorator==4.4.2
Django==3.0.6
dlib==19.19.0
docutils==0.15.2
entrypoints==0.3
face-recognition==1.3.0
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
gast==0.3.3
grpcio==1.14.1
h5py==2.8.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.9
image==1.5.31
imageai==2.1.5
implicit==0.3.7
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
imutils==0.5.3
incremental==17.5.0
ipykernel==5.1.4
ipython==7.13.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
isort==4.3.21
jedi==0.17.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jmespath==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.3
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab==0.34.9
jupyterlab-launcher==0.13.1
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.2.0
labelImg==1.8.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lxml==4.5.0
Markdown==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==2.2.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.0.6
mkl-random==1.0.1
mysql-connector==2.2.9
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.6.0
numpy==1.14.5
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
pandas==1.0.3
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==5.2.0
playsound==1.2.2
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.4
protobuf==3.11.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.6.1
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
pylint==2.4.4
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyQt5==5.14.1
PyQt5-sip==12.7.1
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-binance==0.7.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
pywin32==227
pywinpty==0.5.7
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==18.1.1
qtconsole==4.4.1
regex==2020.2.20
requests==2.23.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.3.3
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.1.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
service-identity==18.1.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
TBB==0.1
tensorboard==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.10.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
tornado==5.1.1
tqdm==4.46.0
traitlets==4.3.3
Twisted==20.3.0
txaio==20.3.1
typed-ast==1.4.1
tzlocal==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.8
wcwidth==0.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
zipp==3.1.0
zope.interface==5.0.1
```

Any help? Thanks.